# Adding cms block to footer links magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

How can I add cms static block to footer as a footer links and view it on my specific store view ? I am using magento 1.9

Answer (score 1):

You can directly add content in footer block that is currently displaying.

So first you need to search in back-end which static block is displaying in footer.

Comment: I want to make an other block and display it on the same place in the footer but in other store view.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a Static Block:

1. Go to the Magento Admin panel and then select the  CMS -> Static Blocks
2. Then Click on the “Add New Block” button from the right top
3. Now fill the following fields:
   Block Title: Give the Name of the static block here. This will not show on the frontend
   Identifier: Give the id of this block. It used as reference of this block, when adding to a template file or CMS page
   Status: Its define visibility of this static block on the frontend
   Content: Content of static block can be plain text, HTML code and Javascript.
4. Click on “Save Block” button.

Showing a Static Block in frontend at footer:

Go to app > design > frontend > your_package > your_theme > layout. Open the appropriate file, lets say page.xml and add the following code inside 
`<block type="page/html_footer name="footer" as="footer" template="page/html/footer.phtml"">` block:

```
<block type="cms/block" name="your_block_id" before="-">
      <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>your_block_id</block_id></action>
</block>
```

Now, refresh the cache at the backend and also the front page to see the cms static block at footer.

To include the block in specific store view:

```
<?php
$Store = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode();
  if($Store == "your-storeview"){
    echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('your_block_id')->toHtml();
  }
  else {
    echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('your_block_id')->toHtml();            
  }
  ?>
```